# Spring Social - Facebook - What is REST API to make signup & signin from iOS with access_token

Tags: java, facebook, jhipster, spring-social

I've generated Java & Angular app that included Facebook configuration for it, and signup/signin demo via Angular is worked good. (I'm using: latest Spring social, security, Auth2)

On iOS side: I have configured Facebook app info and allowed login via Facebook, after that I have Facebook's access_token. But I cannot found the REST API to login via iOS.

I have done 2 steps:

1. Backend: Exposed rest api (/api/v1/social/signup/facebook?accessToken=xxxxxxx). In this RestController, I've created a connection via this token and get UserProfile from Facebook -> Save to database => DONE
2. iOS: Configured Facebook app and get my access_token after logged in Facebook on iOS via Facebook SDK.

**Question**: What can I do for login via Facebook (NOT username/password)?